# SQL Developer get time when query is run

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using sql developer to fire some queries. I want to know the time when query has run. I see that when you fire sql query, you can see "Task completed in x seconds". But here I want to see the time when query got execute. Is there a way like showtimestamp or something?

Comment: Not if you're just looking at existing query results. Are you running as a script - in which case you could just `select systimestamp from dual` before your real query; or as a command - in which case you could maybe add a `systimestanp` (or `sysdate, depends how accurate you want it to be) as an extra column in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual;` if the scripts can be modified.

If that's not an option then right-click on the Worksheet and select SQL History:
[image]